# Anaconda3 not working with the Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssl, anaconda

I've installed Anaconda3 to this Linux subsystem on Windows 10. It works. Commands like `ipython`, `jupyter notebook` works perfectly, exactly like in my Ubuntu system on working computer. `which python` also shows `/home/Dida/anaconda3/bin/python`.

Everything seems to be fine. However, when I'm trying to install `theano`, `pymc3` or just to check `scipy` with `conda install theano` I get following:

```
 Dida@DESKTOP-3H53T9M:~$ conda install theano
 Fetching package metadata ...
 CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2>
 Elapsed: -

 An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
 HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
 SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.continuum.io\',
 port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
 /pkgs/main/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t
 connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",))',),)
```

I don't know how to solve it. I know that this Bash shell is in Beta-version, but everything was fine until today.

And it seems that easiest solution is to install native anaconda for windows... or try to install python without `conda`. But I want to work it in this Bash Shell.

Edit1: When I am typing  `conda config --show` it shows

```
add_anaconda_token: True
add_pip_as_python_dependency: True
allow_non_channel_urls: True
allow_softlinks: False
always_copy: False
always_softlink: False
always_yes: False
anaconda_upload: None
auto_update_conda: True
changeps1: True
channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org
channel_priority: True
channels:
  - defaults
client_ssl_cert: None
client_ssl_cert_key: None
clobber: False
create_default_packages: []
custom_channels:
  pkgs/main: https://repo.continuum.io/
  pkgs/free: https://repo.continuum.io/
  pkgs/r: https://repo.continuum.io/
  pkgs/pro: https://repo.continuum.io/
custom_multichannels:
  defaults: ["https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main", "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free", "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r", "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro"]
  local: []
default_channels:
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro
disallow: []
envs_dirs:
  - /home/Dida/anaconda3/envs
  - /home/Dida/.conda/envs
force: False
json: False
local_repodata_ttl: 1
migrated_channel_aliases: []
non_admin_enabled: True
offline: False
path_conflict: clobber
pinned_packages: []
pkgs_dirs:
  - /home/Dida/anaconda3/pkgs
  - /home/Dida/.conda/pkgs
proxy_servers: {}
quiet: False
remote_connect_timeout_secs: 9.15
remote_max_retries: 3
remote_read_timeout_secs: 60.0
rollback_enabled: True
shortcuts: True
show_channel_urls: None
ssl_verify: True
track_features: []
use_pip: True
verbosity: 0
```

I don't like no ssl certificate part.

Comment: Did you try again later as the error message suggests?

Comment: @darthbith yes, 6 hours. I can wait longer, actually. But I've installed Anaconda3 Windows distribution and in Anaconda Prompt this `conda install theano` works fine. 

In Linux Bash Shell I type  `conda config --show` and it shows that there no certificates for ssl and I worry about it.